# How to implement alerting from SQLite to python service

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlite, triggers

I'm storing sensor data in SQLite. I have a table 'data' that I write to, and a View 'data_view' that I read from. I use computed columns in data_view to calculate how much time has elapsed since a sensor/row was last seen.

An example row in data looks something like this:

id TEXT | distance INTEGER | last_seen TEXT

An example row in data_view looks something like this:

id TEXT | distance=f(minutes_unseen) | minutes_unseen= now - last_seen

'distance ' is a value 0-100 that is computed in the View as a function of minutes_unseen. Essentially, as minutes_unseen grows larger, 'distance' is increased.

How can my Python service be alerted when distance reaches 50 for any row in the View? My service both reads and writes to the database, uses multiple threads for reading and one for writing.

I don't want to create a polling thread to read periodically from the database, the alert needs to be real time (or as close to it as possible).

I've tried setting up an AFTER UPDATE Trigger but I've had no luck. The trigger was only returning old/inaccurate data.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Given that distance is a function of the time, surely you can just call the service periodically, as after a certain time the distance will be the same. Apologies if I'm misunderstanding your question.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).